# what is the function that draw curves in opengl?

Tags: opengl, graphics

i want to know what are the functions in the opengl that allows me to draw curves ?
cause i learned so far only Points , Lines and polygon .
and i'm trying to draw cartoon character in my lab but i have to write that function whose allow me to draw curves .

Comment: Legacy GL has evaluators, (e.g. [`glEvalMesh...`](https://www.opengl.org/sdk/docs/man2/xhtml/glEvalMesh.xml)) but they were never really HW accelerated and have been removed from core profiles in GL 3.2+. You can continue to use them in a compatibility profile or anything GL 3.0 or older, new software is expected to implement them using some combination of vertex/geometry shaders and possibly tessellation shaders; which ***are*** HW accelerated.

Answer (score 5):

OpenGL only supports points, lines and triangles.

https://www.opengl.org/wiki/Primitive

To draw curves you'll need to render multiple lines. (e.g. `GL_LINE_STRIP`)

See: [OpenGL Coordinates from Bezier Curves](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5443653/opengl-coordinates-from-bezier-curves)

For drawing a "cartoon character" you might want to consider using textures instead, or a 3-D model.